# How to make icon as place holder

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have tried to make my image as place holder in jquery mobile but i failed, here is my [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxUUl.jpg) to see what i want and here is my code to make "Icon of Expedia" as place holder.
so when some one touch this icon from mobile devices or click on this icon from desktop browsers a blue square covers this icon and make it prominent.

```
<div data-role="content">

     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="b">
                    <li>
                        <img alt="Hotels.com" src="images/H.jpg" />
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; width: 53%; float: left;">
                            <a style="font-size: 10px; color: Black;">Great Deal- Collect 10 nights and get 1 free
                                at Hotels.com</a>  
                    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: close your `<div>`, please

Comment: I have closed but is there any purpose with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Placeholder using JQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241196/image-placeholder-using-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Omar both are my questions here :)

Comment: hehe :) see again you will find difference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `:active` CSS selector to do that.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/2N7Ja/3/

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="cf">
        <span class="wrapper">
            <img src="image.png"/>
        </span>
        <a>Great Deal- Collect 10 nights and get 1 free at Hotels.com</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
img { display: block; }
#list { list-style: none; }
#list, #list > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#list > li > a {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
#list img {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
}
#list > li:active img {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need to have blue square around image when it is clicked i mean to say after clicking image should be visible having blue rectangle around it.